# How do I select the proprietary nvidia drivers on Fedora 35 after installing them from RPM?

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia

I'm trying Fedora after using Ubuntu for a while. After a fresh Ubuntu install, I would select the nvidia drivers by using the GUI application called "Additional Drivers". I do this because my monitors support 144 Hz refresh rate, which typically only works when I'm using the proprietary drivers. On Fedora, it doesn't for me, with the out of the box install.

For Fedora, I noticed there is no Additional Drivers application and I wasn't able to find a similar application already installed. I found this tutorial which I followed (https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-graphic-drivers-on-fedora-35-gnome-41/) except for the part where you run `su` to change to the root user. This wouldn't work for me because I didn't have a root password. The Fedora install process never prompted me to set one up. I figured it would be fine to run the commands in the tutorial from my user using sudo. So I ended up running the following:

```
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh -y
sudo dnf install dnf-plugins-core -y
sudo dnf install \
  https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
sudo dnf install \
  https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
sudo dnf update --refresh
sudo dnf install akmod-nvidia
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda
```

Then I rebooted my system and when I booted up I ran `nvidia-smi`, as the tutorial says, to check how the install went. Instead of getting the output in the tutorial where it displays information about the driver, I get:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

So it seems like where I'm at right now is that I need to select the driver now that I've installed it. How do I do this?

Data about my system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five)
Release:    35
Codename:   ThirtyFive
```

Card: 3070 Ti

Comment: BTW, the instructions to follow are here: https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA

Comment: The important part of the instructions you missed were to wait for the module to be built.

Comment: Thanks, those instructions look more comprehensive than the ones I found. When I run `modinfo -F version nvidia` it says `510.47.03`, so I think this means it was able to finish building the module before I restarted earlier. But the instructions also say that secure boot has to be disabled in order for the driver to be loaded by the kernel. Is this a one time thing where I disable it, boot, then re-enable it, and get to keep using the driver? Or does this mean I need to disable secure boot and keep it disabled to use my Linux boot? If so, would that cause issues with my Windows 11 boot?

Comment: This also may explain why I began to have issues with my display drivers in my Ubuntu boot. I enabled secure boot and disk encryption in Windows 10 a few months ago. I did that in order to qualify for the upgrade to Windows 11. And then at some point in time, I went back into my Ubuntu boot and noticed that I was back down to the nouveau drivers. I didn't put the two things together until now (because until now, I wasn't aware of something lower level than the OS being involved in loading a graphics driver) but now it makes sense.

Comment: While it is technically possible to add your own signing key to your OS firmware, and sign the nvidia module, most people just run without secure boot enabled.

Comment: From a quick google, I gathered that it's not going to break my system to disable Secure Boot. Windows would just prompt me to enter a recovery key to boot up each time until I re-enable it. So I disabled it for now, and when I booted up Fedora, it worked great. The proprietary driver was running by default and my 144 Hz settings worked. For now, I'll deal with this BIOS switch each time and later I'll look into whether adding my own signing key is the right choice for me. Thanks a lot for your help. If you copy your comments into an answer, I'll make it the accepted answer.